# How to generate DocumentHeader for each file in wpf c# application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to generate Document Header for each file in WPF C# Appplication develop in visual studio 2015.

Comment: Not sure the question is very clear.  Do you mean a Document Header on each Window  in your application?  Or do you mean a document header when generating an XPS file?

Comment: No I want commant at the beginning of every .cs file which contain filename ,version,product name,comapany name.Which should update automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The [License Header Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5647a099-77c9-4a49-91c3-94001828e99e) extension lets you assign headers to all source files.